# XPath: Get value of last sibling in a node

Tags: xml, xpath, siblings

I am trying to create an XPath expression for use in MS InfoPath in order to retrieve the value of the last sibling in a node. (Hopefully I am phrasing this question correctly as I've barely ever used XPath).

I need to identify the most recent instance of the "NamesEval" node inside the "RepeaterGroup" node. Hypothetically I will be looking to see if "Steve" is attending the latest event; I will check for this using a `contains(LatestEvent, "Steve")` XPath expression. How do I get "LatestEvent" to load in only the most recent "NamesEval" value?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.2" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\db543e141b8f4832\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?><my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-09-07T14:19:10" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:InitialSection>
    <my:InitialField>1</my:InitialField>
    <my:InitialDate>2012-09-14</my:InitialDate>
</my:InitialSection>
<my:RepeaterSection>
    <my:RepeaterGroup>
        <my:RepeaterField>2</my:RepeaterField>
        <my:RepeaterDate>2012-09-15</my:RepeaterDate>
            <my:NamesGroup>
                <my:NamesRepeater>
                    <my:Name>Steve</my:Name>
                </my:NamesRepeater>
                <my:NamesRepeater>
                    <my:Name>Ashley</my:Name>
                </my:NamesRepeater>
                <my:NamesRepeater>
                    <my:Name>Josh</my:Name>
                </my:NamesRepeater>
            </my:NamesGroup>
        <my:NamesEval>Steve;Ashley;Josh;</my:NamesEval>
    </my:RepeaterGroup>
    <my:RepeaterGroup>
        <my:RepeaterField>3</my:RepeaterField>
        <my:RepeaterDate>2012-09-16</my:RepeaterDate>
        <my:NamesGroup>
            <my:NamesRepeater>
                <my:Name>Amanda</my:Name>
            </my:NamesRepeater>
            <my:NamesRepeater>
                <my:Name>Greg</my:Name>
            </my:NamesRepeater>
            <my:NamesRepeater>
                <my:Name>Steve</my:Name>
            </my:NamesRepeater>
            </my:NamesGroup>
        <my:NamesEval>Amanda;Greg;Steve;</my:NamesEval>
    </my:RepeaterGroup>
</my:RepeaterSection>
```

**EDIT & ANSWER**

Choroba answered the question below - here is the solution: `//my:RepeaterGroup[0=count(following-sibling::my:RepeaterGroup)]//my:NamesEval`

Comment: BTW, a more idiomatic version of your solution is `//my:RepeaterGroup[not(following-sibling::my:RepeaterGroup)]//my:NamesEval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. If you are trying to verify that the last NamesEval contains the string "Steve", you can use the following XPath expression:

```
contains((//my:NamesEval)[last()],'Steve')
```

Comment: Ugh - InfoPath says "position and last are not supported". That works like a champ in the Notepad++ XML Tools XPath evaluator. CURSE YOU MICROSOFT!!!!!!!!

Comment: It has to be web enabled... This expression has promise, though I don't fully understand it `//my:NamesEval[count(following-sibling::my:NamesEval) = 0]`. In NPP++ it still returns all the nodes...

Comment: @Chris: `NamesEval`s are not siblings.

Comment: Ok - my terminology is wrong (I figured that might be the case); how would they be defined? I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Chris: probably `//my:RepeaterGroup[0=count(following-sibling::my:RepeaterGroup)]//my:NamesEval`?

Comment: !!! That works perfectly !!!! I cannot even tell you how greatful I am! Looks like the weekend will be a good one after all :D I adapted your initial expression to the modified one you just posted and it gives me *exactly* what I need. Thanks so much! `contains(//my:RepeaterGroup[0=count(following-sibling::my:RepeaterGroup)]//my:NamesEval,'Steve')`