# Return "latest" node in repeating node set

Tags: xml, xpath, repeat

I need to adapt the following XPath expression to return the "Latest" `Amend_Start_Date` from the sample XML (from MS InfoPath):

```
//my:Amend_Data[0=count(following-sibling::my:Amend_Data)]//my:Amend_Start_Date
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.440" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\1c02663d7ed84d09\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?><?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?><my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-05T19:56:08" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:MasterSection>
    <my:Planning_Section>
        <my:Planned_Start_Date>2012-09-12</my:Planned_Start_Date>
        <my:Planned_End_Date>2012-09-14</my:Planned_End_Date>
    </my:Planning_Section>
    <my:Actual_Section>
        <my:Actual_Start_Date>2012-09-13</my:Actual_Start_Date>
        <my:Actual_End_Date>2012-09-15</my:Actual_End_Date>
    </my:Actual_Section>
    <my:Amend_Hider>
        <my:Amend_Info_Repeater_Group>
            <my:Amend_Info_Repeater>
                <my:Amend_Data>
                    <my:Amend_Start_Date>2012-09-16</my:Amend_Start_Date>
                    <my:Amend_End_Date>2012-09-21</my:Amend_End_Date>
                </my:Amend_Data>
            </my:Amend_Info_Repeater>
            <my:Amend_Info_Repeater>
                <my:Amend_Data>
                    <my:Amend_Start_Date>2012-09-23</my:Amend_Start_Date>
                    <my:Amend_End_Date>2012-09-27</my:Amend_End_Date>
                </my:Amend_Data>
            </my:Amend_Info_Repeater>
        </my:Amend_Info_Repeater_Group>
    </my:Amend_Hider>
</my:MasterSection>
```

I started using XPath last Thursday... So forgive me if I am in need of spoonfeeding. As it stands the listed expression returns *all* start date nodes from the sample XML. It is intended to return the "Latest" `Amend_Start_Date` but does not because the structure of the XML is such that the `Amend_Start_Date` nodes are not grouped together. In this example that would mean a correct expression would return a start date of `2012-09-23` and **NOT** `2012-09-16`

There must be a way this can be accomplished! Somehow the relative path of the `Amend_Data` node must be modified... Any help is appreciated!

**PS:** This relates to a question I posted on Friday that [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323195/xpath-get-value-of-last-sibling-in-a-node/12323336#12323336). You may note the structural difference in the sample XML listed in that question v. this one.

Comment: At this point I have restructured my data so that "Amend_Data" no longer exists. In this way the original XPath expression still functions. I will leave this question open for the moment, however, as I would still very much like to know if there is an XPath expression that can accomodate this.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that by "latest date" you mean the highest (nmaximum) date? If so, this isn't possible to get evaluationg a single XPath 1.0 expression. It is possible to get evaluating a single XPath 2.0 expression. If you have available an XPath 2.0 implementation to use, then let me know and I will post the XPath 2.0 answer.

Comment: Dimitre - thanks for responding. I mean the most recent occurance of that node. I.E. I make a new form with info about an event or project. That becomes an actual plan but it can be amended. Therefore I want the "start date" and "end date" to always be from the latest amendment. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Still not clear. Does "latest" means with the highest date, or does it mean "last in document order" ?

Comment: Last in document order. Planned Start Date: Jan 1 - Actual Start Date: Dec 31 - Amended Start Date 1: Dec 30 - Amended Start Date 2: Dec 29. You see that it is not chronological but according to placement in the document.

Comment: Then the XPath expression in my answer selects exactly the wanted element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
(//my:Amend_Data)[last()]//my:Amend_Start_Date
```

should do the trick.

Without using `last()` you can try:

```
//my:Amend_Info_Repeater[0=count(following-sibling::my:Amend_Info_Repeater)]/my:Amend_Data/my:Amend_Start_Date
```

Comment: Thanks! You're probably right but this form will have to be web enabled and for some reason MS InfoPath does not support position information. But I will upvote your answer!

Comment: This is strange - I did a quick search and landed at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/about-xpath-HP001096732.aspx, where they explicitely mention `last()`. Do you get an error? Or the wrong result? Maybe there is something else going on (e.g the XML is not the one you are expecting..)

Comment: ...I had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323195/xpath-get-value-of-last-sibling-in-a-node, saw that you are getting an error from InfoPath...forget my question...

Comment: ..I added an alternative solution based on the answer you got from your previous question

Comment: That works a treat! I didn't understand how to append the remainder of the path to end of the expression. This helps clarify things greatly! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
(//my:Amend_Start_Date)[last()]
```

This selects the last (in document order) of all `my:Amend_Start_Date` elements in the XML document.

**Update**:

If due to some bug/incompliance in InfoPath's XPath implementation the above expression cannot be evaluated successfully/correctly, try:

```
//my:Amend_Start_Date
    [not(preceding::my:Amend_Start_Date or ancestor::my:Amend_Start_Date)]
```

Comment: Dimitre - this does work with XPath 2.0; Unfortunatlely web enabled InfoPath forms don't support position expressions. But it is a valid answer if you can use XPath 2.0! I'll give you an upvote for it, and thank you!

Comment: @Chris, No, This works with XPath 1.0 -- there might be some problem/bug with InfoPath's evaluation of XPath expressions. My guess is that it doesn't support namespace prefixes (without the association (prefix, ns-uri) having been registered. Try: `(//*[name()='my:Amend_Start_Date'])[last()]` . Also, please, see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't got it in one xpath but maybe the xslt helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-05T19:56:08">
    <xsl:output method = "text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="y" select="//my:Amend_Data"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="$y[count($y)]/my:Amend_Start_Date"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$x"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```